# why there are class variables in ruby?

Tags: ruby, language-design, class-variables

If creating a class variable is often dangerous and unpredictable why do we need them? 
If solution is just to use class instance variable with the class level accessors:

```
class Foo
  @variable = :something

  def self.getvariable
    @variable
  end

  def self.setvariable(value)
    @variable = value
  end
end
```

Then why do we need class variables???

Comment: Why is it "dangerous and unpredictable"?

Comment: because all class variables are accessible within all inheritance tree => they can be modified by subclasses. Look it here http://sporkmonger.com/2007/2/19/instance-variables-class-variables-and-inheritance-in-ruby

Comment: You need class variables if you have class hierarchy and need to share some data among classes in some hierarchy tree.

Comment: taro, so, we should use them only like constants in subclasses and not modify their values?

Comment: Sergey, I really don't see your point. This is perfectly acceptable in OOP.

Comment: @Sergey That doesn't make them "dangerous and unpredictable". They're very predictable, they just aren't class-level instance variables

Comment: Roland, please, visit the link in the second comment. You'll see that class variables in a couple with inheritance is a dead thing. Trying to change class variable from one subclass will change it not only in this very subclass, but in the whole interitance tree.

Comment: @Sergey, Sure, however, you may find this quite useful at times. Especially when you work with a foreign library and you want to modify how a component/class works, but don't want to understand every bit of the initial class. Additionally, this is not ruby specific. C# does similar things with the "new" keyword.

Comment: They are not "dangerous and unpredictable", we, programmers are...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class variables have their use on occasion, but I agree that using the eigenclass is frequently more useful:

```
class Foo
  @bar = 'bar'
  class << self
    attr_accessor :bar
  end
end

puts Foo.bar         # bar
puts Foo.bar = 'baz' # baz
```

The above is safe with inheritance, because it sets a variable in the Foo constant, rather than a class variable.

```
Foo.new.instance_eval { puts @@bar } # error
```

Comment: thanks for your opinion, but I wanna see what occasion are you talking about because as for me, I think that class variables - is an odd thing in Ruby

Comment: I didn't say they weren't odd. Just that, when you want all classes in a tree to share some data, they're convenient.

Answer (score 1):

This has several causes:

1. It's syntactic sugar. You can always get a class variable (whether you are in class or instance scope) using `@@var`. This won't work for instance variables of the class.
2. Class variables persist for the singleton classes of the instances of this class. Example:

   ```
   class Test

     @instance_var = 0
     @@class_var = 0

     def self.instance_var
       @instance_var
     end

     def self.class_var
       @@class_var
     end

   end

   Test.instance_var #=> 0
   Test.class_var #=> 0
   Test.new.singleton_class.instance_var #=> nil
   Test.new.singleton_class.class_var #=> 0
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example (think ActiveRecord):

```
class Base
  def connect(connection)
    @@connection = connection
  end

  def connection
    @@connection
  end
end

class User < Base
end

class SuperUser < User
end

Base.new.connect("A connection")
puts User.new.connection      #=> A connection
puts SuperUser.new.connection #=> A connection
```

The trick here is that class variable is accessible from an instance method and is inherited. Try this:

```
class Base
  def self.connect(connection)
    @connection = connection
  end

  def self.connection
    @connection
  end

  def connection
    self.class.connection
  end
end

class User < Base
end

Base.connect("A connection")
puts User.new.connection #=> nil
```

You will get `nil` as `self.connection` tries to access it's own class instance variable (from `User` class), and it is not inherited.

**Added:** And yes, it can be dangerous if you misuse it:

```
@@a = "A"

class A
  def self.a
    @@a
  end
  def a
    @@a
  end
end

puts A.a     #=> A
puts A.new.a #=> A
```